# How to set timeout to a PowerShell function?

Tags: powershell, timeout

I have a script which is fetching the disk space information of many machines in a call center. However, sometimes this function takes too long. I need to create a time out for that function and have been unable to. I tried using start-job but to be honest, I don't fully understand it and so I am not getting the desired results.

```
try {
    $timeoutSeconds = 30
    $code = {
      param($currentPCname, $activeDriveTypes)
// Function which takes computer name as input and outputs the ComputerName,DeviceID, Size, Freespace and DriveType (3 = local)
      function get-FDS { 
        [cmdLetBinding()]
        Param([string]$hostName)
        Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $hostName | 
        Where-object {$_.DriveType -in $activeDriveTypes} | 
        select-Object @{Name="ComputerName";Expression={$hostName}}, @{Name="Date";Expression={Get-Date}}, DeviceID, Size, Freespace, DriveType
      } 
      get-FDS($currentPCname) -errorAction stop
    }
    $processTime = measure-command { 
      $j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -Arg $currentPCname, $activeDriveTypes 
      if (Wait-Job $j -Timeout $timeoutSeconds) { $tempData = Receive-Job $j }
      $jobState = $j.state
      Remove-Job -force $j
    }
    if ($jobState -ne 'Completed') {
        $pcTurnedOn = $false
        $errorMessage = "ERROR talking to $currentPCname : Query timed-out"
        $query = "CALL sp_fds_insert_log(" + $currentRunID + ", '" + $errorMessage + "', '" + $scriptName + "');"
        $cmd = new-object mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlcommand($query, $conn) 
        $cmd.executenonquery()
    }
} catch {
    $pcTurnedOn = $false
    $errorMessage = "ERROR talking to $currentPCname : $_"
    $query = "CALL sp_fds_insert_log(" + $currentRunID + ", '" + $errorMessage + "', '" + $scriptName + "');"
    $cmd = new-object mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlcommand($query, $conn) 
    $cmd.executenonquery() 
}
```

The main point of the code above is that if the line below which is calling the $code segment

```
$processTime = measure-command { 
  $j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -Arg $currentPCname, $activeDriveTypes
  if (Wait-Job $j -Timeout $timeoutSeconds) { $tempData = Receive-Job $j }
  $jobState = $j.state
  Remove-Job -force $j
}
```

takes more than 30 seconds which is the $timeoutSeconds, the last IF statement would be called, if the line above does not work for some reason, the catch statement would be called and if it works in less than 30 seconds, nothing would be called.

Comment: `Start-Job` returns a job object immediately, so when you do `Measure-Command {$j = Start-Job ...}` it's never going to take more than a few milliseconds

Comment: I understand, however, the problem is not the $processTime result as that can be easily fixed, what I am having a hard time with is letting the job run for maximum 30 seconds and then killing it. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: I've fixed that part, any ideas for the timeout buddy? @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the job finished before the timeout is reached, `Wait-Job` will return the job itself - if the timeout is exceeded it won't return anything:

```
$timeout = 2
$job = Start-Job { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 }
$done = $job |Wait-Job -TimeOut $timeout
if($done){
    # It returned within the timeout 
}
else {
    # Nothing was returned, job timed out
}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy very helpful :)

Comment: @EnriqueMingyarTorrezHinojos Thanks. I'm afraid I don't understand your question :)